# Converting String to Double not working for bigger values in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, string, double

I simply would like to convert a `String` into a `Double` . This is the function I am using for this:

```
private func calculateListPrice(index: Int) -> Double {
    var price = Double(0.0)
    for wish in self.dataSourceArray[index].wishes {
        var priceTrimmed = wish.price.trimmingCharacters(in: CharacterSet(charactersIn: "0123456789.").inverted)
        priceTrimmed = priceTrimmed.replacingOccurrences(of: ",", with: ".")
        print(priceTrimmed)
        if let doublePrice = Double(priceTrimmed) {
            price += doublePrice
            // return value * 100 so updateAmount calculates correct Int Value
        }
    }
    let rounded = Double(round(100*price)/100)
    print(rounded)
    return rounded
}
```

The problem is that this not working with every number. Here are a free example:

> no: 999.999.99
>
> yes: 2.22
>
> yes: 505.05
>
> yes: 31.11
>
> no: 3.111.50
>
> yes: 999.99
>
> no: 2.000.00

Comment: What means " 999.999.99" for you? 999999.99 ? (99 after the "unit")? Are you looking for NumberFormatter instead?

Comment: @Larme not sure tbh, never used it before but I mean 999999.99

Comment: `replacingOccurrences(of: ",", with: ".")` don't do this if ',' is the thousand separator.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson how do I do that?

Comment: Not sure what you are asking but I would suggest you use a NumberFormatter configured to match your data for the conversion.

Comment: Never ever hardcode `,` & `.` when you're working with numbers. String `10,000.21` (en-US might be your locale) represents the same number as string `10 000,21` (cs-CZ is my locale). If I run your app with my locale and enter a number in my way, it wont work. Use [`NSNumberFormatter`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsnumberformatter) and [`Locale.decimalSeparator`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/locale/2292886-decimalseparator) & [`Locale.groupingSeparator`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/locale/2292942-groupingseparator).

Comment: @JoakimDanielson could you elaborate on that? Never used it before

Comment: See comment from @zrzka but of course use [NumberFormatter](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/numberformatter) instead.

Comment: Could you share the value of "wish.price"? show that make a number-formatter function to convert the string value in Double.

Comment: @AshutoshkumarMishra I gave exaples in the question. wish.price is the same but with a "€" and a "," instead of "."

Comment: @JoakimDanielson which is why Im not too sure if I actually need a `NumberFormatter`

Comment: @Chris, As I understand the value of "wish.price" = "9999,99€" in this format. So you can use it as german or french currency number-formatter for that.

Comment: _wish.price is the same but with a "€" and a ","_ but then it isn't the same, please add examples of the real content of `wish.price`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You can use number-formatter by setting their style as a currency type. I have implemented an example as follows:-**

```
let formatter = NumberFormatter()
let frenchFormat = Locale(identifier: "fr_FR")
let germanFormat = Locale(identifier: "de_DE")

formatter.numberStyle = .currency

formatter.locale = frenchFormat

if let frenchPriceValue = formatter.number(from: "100,96€"){
    print(frenchPriceValue) //Output is:- 100.96
}
```

**OR**

```
formatter.locale = germanFormat
if let germanPriceValue = formatter.number(from: "123,33€"){
   print(germanPriceValue)//Output is:- 123.33
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should probably use [NumberFormatter](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/numberformatter), since it supports parsing currency (like you are trying to do), and is easier and less likely to break than using a manual approach.

So, for example, if you want to parse currency, using the current user's locale, you would use:

```swift
func priceToDouble(price: String) -> Double? {
    let currencyFormatter = NumberFormatter()
    currencyFormatter.usesGroupingSeparator = true
    currencyFormatter.numberStyle = .currency
    currencyFormatter.locale = Locale.current
    
    guard let result = currencyFormatter.number(from: price) else { return nil }
    return Double(result)
}
```

It will parse the currency amount based on the locale, so, for example, if the user's locale was set to US, it would convert "$1,234.56" into Double(1234.56). If the users locale was to Europe, it would convert "€2.345,60" into Double(2345.6)

You can also manually set the locale, so, by replacing `currencyFormatter.locale = Locale.current` with `currencyFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "eu")` will cause it to always use the European currency format.